# Suddenly Application is blank in android Something wrong with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am developing an app with the help of fragment. I am getting blank screen(white). There are following two cases:

1. If application goes in background & we open another applications & when again i come on own application then it is blank .
2. If i open camera or other native app through intent then on back press, when i come on app it is blank.

I am not getting any error in logcat.
Please suggest what resion behind this?
Answer would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the code in onPause and onResume function?

Comment: Please share your code in order to debug your problem.

Comment: in onPause i don't have nothing But onResume i have @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  Fragment topFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
  if (topFragment instanceof TakeTestListingFragment) {
   topFragment.onResume();
  }
 }
And onSaveInstanceState is empty